# How can we verify that Image carousel auto switch in three seconds in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What is the process to verify that the Image carousel contents auto switch in three seconds in `Selenium WebDriver`?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing how the carousel works, but a general solution would be check for the element with whatever class makes it active/visible, wait 3 seconds, find the element that is now active and check it's not the same element.

Comment: carousel are set of images which switches on click arrow right or left.